# Command for taking exe and all supporting files(dll's and xml) for dotfuscation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, obfuscation, dotfuscator

I am using dotfuscator for the protecting of my `hello.exe` and supporting files like

- hello.dll
- hello.xml

But the problem is that dotfuscator is taking input as only `hello.exe` file,and dotfuscate it.
But it's not executing.
I think after the dotfuscation the dll & xml is not supporting to the exe. 
I am using command

```
 "dotfuscator -in:C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Hello\bin\x86\Debug\Hello.exe"
```

It's working fine,but the command

```
"dotfuscator -in:C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Hello\bin\x86\Debug\Hello.exe,Hello.dll,Hello.xml"
```

The given error is 
**"Input assembly Hello.dll does not exist"**
even though Hello.dll is also there.

Comment: Is hello.dll a native or managed dll?

Comment: that contradicts your comment to the deleted answer. You also do need the full path of the dll. How do you expect the .xml file to be obfuscated?

Comment: I have also use this command "
dotfuscator -in:C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Hello\bin\x86\Debug\Hello.exe,C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Hello\bin\x86\Debug\Hello.dll" But the error is same as previous.

Comment: that's not what you said in the comment to the deleted answer. There you said error was: Invalid Input
assembly Hello.dll.This is not a managed module. Hello.dll.This is not a managed module.

Comment: ok,suppose the dll is native,then what should I do?

Comment: No need to obfuscate native DLL, compiler already did that!

Answer (score 1):

You need to start DotFuscator from the directory where the DLL and EXE files are located.
In your case this is `C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Hello\bin\x86\Debug\`

As an alternative you could pass the **full path** to every component after the /in switch

e.g.

```
"dotfuscator -in:C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Hello\bin\x86\Debug\Hello.exe,C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Hello\bin\x86\Debug\Hello.dll
```

Comment: I have also use this but error occur.The error is "Invalid Input assembly Hello.dll.This is not a managed module"

Comment: I've undeleted the answer as it solves your original problem. For that new error I don't want to steal credits from David

Comment: @yas I'm not answering on this one, go for as much credit as you like!

Comment: @David You've already answered it in the comments to the question. No credits left :)

Comment: is not worked gives no information. Dotfuscator tells you it's not a managed DLL.

Comment: @vikky There is no easy solution for your problem. You could of course implement the behaviour of the native DLL in managed code.